# Recibir emails con Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

Estoy tratando de recibir con Python los correos que tengo en mi Gmail. Me conecto sin problemas a mi cuenta y consigo sacar el correo del que ha enviado el mensaje, el tema o la hora de entrega, pero no hay forma de conseguir el cuerpo del mensaje. Os dejo aqui mi codigo y os explico:

```
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email

def read_email_from_gmail():
try:
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('micorreo@gmail.com','micontraseña')
    mail.select('inbox')

    type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()   
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


    for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
        typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_from = msg['from']
                email_date = msg['Date']
                email_body = msg['body']
                print 'From : ' + email_from + '\n'
                print 'Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n'
                print 'Date : ' + email_date + '\n'
                print 'Body : ' + email_body + '\n'

except Exception, e:
   print "Exception"
read_email_from_gmail()
```

Como veis para conseguir por ejemplo la fecha lo hago con `msg['Date']` , pero no consigo algo que me devuelva el cuerpo del mensaje. He probado con Body y main, y no se me ocurre nada mas. Gracias de antemano.

********Actualizacion 11 de Septiembre************

He actualizado el codigo tal y como me dijiste, ahora estoy mas cerca, pero todavia faltan cosas.

```
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email

def read_email_from_gmail():
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        mail.login('micorreo@gmail.com','micontraseña')
        mail.select('inbox')

       type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
       mail_ids = data[0]

       id_list = mail_ids.split()   
       first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
       latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


       for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
           typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

           for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                    if msg.is_multipart():
                        for part in msg.walk():       
                            if part.get_content_type() in ("text/plain",   "text/html"):
                                print(part.get_payload(decode = True))
                    else: 
                        print(part.get_payload(decode = True))


    except Exception, e:
       print "\n"
read_email_from_gmail()
```

Con ese codigo este es el output que consigo:

Esto es una prueba #Aqui me aparece un cuadrado extraño

Esto es una prueba
 #Aqui me aparece otra vez el mensaje, pero con varias cosas de html como div y br, pero que al escribirlo en StackOverflow no aparecen. Se puede "limpiar" un poco mas el codigo? Gracias.

Comment: Andermutu ¿usas Python 2 o Python 3? Pones la etiqueta Python 3.x pero ese código es de Python 2....

Comment: Si estoy utilizando python 2. Perdona

Comment: No te preocupes, no tengo demasiada experiencia en el manejo de mensajes con Python 2. En Python 3 si los he manejado más a menudo pero  es algo diferente. Te he dejado una respuesta a ver si te funciona. Lo he testeado con outlook y un mensaje con texto enriquecido (text/html) y funciona sin incidentes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`email.message.get_payload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload). Previamente debes filtrar por tipo de contenido:

```
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.walk():       
        if part.get_content_type() in ("text/plain", "text/html"):
            print(part.get_payload(decode = True))
else: 
    print(part.get_payload(decode = True))
```

Con esto obtendrás el contenido que sea texto plano o texto enriquezido (html), otros contenidos como un pdf adjunto (tipo `application/pdf`) no serán lógicamente imprimidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla! Mañana lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: He avanzado mucho, pero todavia le falta un poco. He actualizado la pregunta, alguna propuesta?

Comment: @Andermutu si he entendido lo que obtienes es parte del mensaje con código html. Si el mensaje contiene texto enriquecido (cosa muy común, subrallado, negrita,fuente) vas a obtener un string con el contenido html. Si lo guardas en un archivo html puedes abrirlo en un navegador y se te formateará en principio igual que lo ves en tu cliente de email. Puedes pasar este texto a texto plano con algunas bibliotecas si quieres eliminar el html. Esto no es problema del módulo `email`, simplemente el contenido del email es un texto html que el cliente se encarga de renderizar para mostrarlo al usuario.

Comment: eso es, consigo el mensaje con codigo html. Que bibliotecas son necesarias para eliminarlo?

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, desde crear tu propio render usando la bibliotca estándar con html.parser o usar algo ya existente. Si solo quieres obtner el texto (solo eliminar las etiquetas sin mantener los parraffos, saltos de linea...,etc) puedes usar [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (usando el método `get_text()`) o [lxml](http://lxml.de/) , otra opción más similar aun render html es [html2text] que si ten mantedrá el formato en lo posible (parrafos, saltos de línea...)(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text).

Comment: @Andermutu Pasar el html a texto plano va a significar perder información (negrita, subrayados, párrafos, viñetas,  enlaces, tamaño de fuente, tipografia, color, etc ), es decir obtendrás el texto pero perderás todo lo que aporta el rich-text que es la razón de usar html.